# Get dynamic counter inside of HTML pages using angualr service

Tags: angular

I want to display count above on link. For that I am having one html tag as below

```
<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#" [routerLink]="['/viewcart']">View cart<span class="badge my-badge">2</span></a>
```

Above code is working fine. As you can see 2 is the static number but I need to get dynamic counter from one service.

For that I am having one service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  public shoppingCartData: 10;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }  
}
```

From that service I need to display count. I need to get this value inside of above HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.ts` file of the component, you should inject your service.

`constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}`

Then use it on your code, for example:

`ngOnInit() { this.componentVariable = this.cartService.shoppingCartData; }`

And in your html code, bind your variable.

`<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#" [routerLink]="['/viewcart']">View cart<span class="badge my-badge">{{ componentVariable }}</span></a>`

For your reference about data binding, you can check [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#types-of-data-binding).

Comment: Beat me by seconds but almost verbatim what I was typing haha +1